# repopulating a uipickerview with a .plist file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uipickerview

I have 4 .plist files which I want to use to populate a UIPickerView through a slider, now I am able to populate the first one in the ViewDidLoad method which is the "WeightUnits" one.

Now the slider has the values from 1 to 4 starting at one when the view is loaded, but when I slide to the right (value 2) it should repopulate the UIPickerView with the next .plist file but for some reason it crashes, and I think I know where the reason resides but I can't find a solution.
(I added a comment within the code)

note:
the UIPickerView is connected to the controllers delegate and datasource

Thanks in advance for any help/solution

import UIKit

class ConverterScript: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

```
fileprivate let convertFromComponent = 0
fileprivate let convertToComponent = 1
fileprivate var convertFromTo:[String : [String]]!
fileprivate var convertFrom:[String]!
fileprivate var convertTo:[String]!
@IBOutlet weak var sliderLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var converterPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var valueField: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var resultUnitOfMeasure: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sliderLabel.text = "Weight"

    let bundle = Bundle.main
    let plistURL = bundle.url(forResource: "WeightUnits", withExtension: ".plist")
    convertFromTo = NSDictionary(contentsOf: plistURL!) as! [String: [String]]
    let allWeights = convertFromTo.keys
    convertFrom = allWeights.sorted()

    let selectedWeight = convertFrom[0]
    convertTo = convertFromTo[selectedWeight]
    converterPicker.reloadComponent(convertFromComponent)
    converterPicker.reloadComponent(convertToComponent)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func ifSliderChanges(_ sender: UISlider) {

    sliderLabel.text = "\(lroundf(sender.value))"

    if (sender.value < 1.5) {
        sliderLabel.text = "Weight"

        let bundle = Bundle.main
        let plistURL = bundle.url(forResource: "WeightUnits", withExtension: ".plist")
        convertFromTo = NSDictionary(contentsOf: plistURL!) as! [String: [String]]
        let allWeights = convertFromTo.keys
        convertFrom = allWeights.sorted()

        let selectedWeight = convertFrom[0]
        convertTo = convertFromTo[selectedWeight]
        converterPicker.reloadComponent(convertFromComponent)
        converterPicker.reloadComponent(convertToComponent)

        converterPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: convertFromComponent, animated: true)
        converterPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: convertToComponent, animated: true)
    } else if (sender.value >= 1.5 && sender.value <= 2.5){
        sliderLabel.text = "Volume"

        let bundle = Bundle.main
        let plistURL = bundle.url(forResource: "VolumeUnits", withExtension: ".plist")
        //issue starts here according to Xcode Debugging!!!!!
        convertFromTo = NSDictionary(contentsOf: plistURL!) as! [String: [String]]
        let allWeights = convertFromTo.keys
        convertFrom = allWeights.sorted()

        let selectedWeight = convertFrom[0]
        convertTo = convertFromTo[selectedWeight]
        converterPicker.reloadComponent(convertFromComponent)
        converterPicker.reloadComponent(convertToComponent)

        converterPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: convertFromComponent, animated: true)
        converterPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: convertToComponent, animated: true)
    }else if (sender.value >= 2.5 && sender.value <= 3.5){
        sliderLabel.text = "Length"

        let bundle = Bundle.main
        let plistURL = bundle.url(forResource: "LengthUnits", withExtension: ".plist")
        convertFromTo = NSDictionary(contentsOf: plistURL!) as! [String: [String]]
        let allWeights = convertFromTo.keys
        convertFrom = allWeights.sorted()

        let selectedWeight = convertFrom[0]
        convertTo = convertFromTo[selectedWeight]
        converterPicker.reloadComponent(convertFromComponent)
        converterPicker.reloadComponent(convertToComponent)

        converterPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: convertFromComponent, animated: true)
        converterPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: convertToComponent, animated: true)
    }
    else if (sender.value > 3.5){
        sliderLabel.text = "Temperature"

        let bundle = Bundle.main
        let plistURL = bundle.url(forResource: "TemperatureUnits", withExtension: ".plist")
        convertFromTo = NSDictionary(contentsOf: plistURL!) as! [String: [String]]
        let allWeights = convertFromTo.keys
        convertFrom = allWeights.sorted()

        let selectedWeight = convertFrom[0]
        convertTo = convertFromTo[selectedWeight]
        converterPicker.reloadComponent(convertFromComponent)
        converterPicker.reloadComponent(convertToComponent)

        converterPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: convertFromComponent, animated: true)
        converterPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: convertToComponent, animated: true)
    }

}

@IBAction func onButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let convertFromRow = converterPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: convertFromComponent)
    let convertToRow = converterPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: convertToComponent)

    let from = convertFrom[convertFromRow]
    let to = convertTo[convertToRow]

    if valueField.text?.isEmpty ?? true {
        let title = "error"
        let message = "please enter a value"

        let alert = UIAlertController(
            title: title,
            message: message,
            preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(
            title: "OK",
            style: .default,
            handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else{
        if (slider.value < 1.5) {

        } else if (slider.value >= 1.5 && slider.value <= 2.5){

        }else if (slider.value >= 2.5 && slider.value <= 3.5){

        }
        else if (slider.value > 3.5){

        }
    }

    resultUnitOfMeasure.text = "\(to)"
}


func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if component == convertFromComponent {
        return convertFrom.count
    } else {
        return convertTo.count
    }
}

//Picker View Delegate Method
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if component == convertFromComponent {
        return convertFrom[row]
    } else {
        return convertTo[row]
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if component == convertFromComponent {
        let selectedWeight = convertFrom[row]
        convertTo = convertFromTo[selectedWeight]
        converterPicker.reloadComponent(convertToComponent)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is crash log showing. Also instead of reading every time from plist file in slider action you need to read it once for all files in viewDidLoad and save in some array

Comment: I will try that, thanks for the help.

Comment: Hello Nirav, The code seemed to be OK, the problem was in my .plist files. they were incomplete, 3 out of the 4 .plist files had no data to populate the 2nd component of the pickerview. It's working now

Comment: Thats ok but batter if you extract all the plists file data in viewDidLoad as of you are currently reading from plist file every time you scroll slider